# C# EFCore DbContext не добавляет записи после исключения

Tags: c#, база-данных, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Если у меня есть некоторый DbContext, в котором есть некоторая таблица Entity, то при выполнении следующих инструкций

```
Entity[] entities = { ... };
DbContext dbContext = new();
foreach (var entity in entities)
{
    try
    {
        await dbContext.Set<Entity>.AddAsync(entity);
        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync():
    }
    catch
    {
        // Logging
    }
}
```

в бд будут добавляться все записи до первого исключения, потом, на записе, которая спровоцировала исключение [1], я логирую, но все остальные записи не добавляются в бд, я всегда попадаю в блок catch и ловлю исключение, которое получил в [1].
В чем природа данного явления и как это исправить?

PS ситуация искусственная, меня интересует, что надо делать с контекстом после первого исключения.

Comment: а можно хотя бы ошибку....

Comment: так то если ошибка с entity все нормально отработает, а вот если с dbContext то ее надо устранять

Comment: @PavloKhyzhniak, ну, например, если я добавляю запись с полем null, а в бд это поле not null, выпадет исключение. Окей, я так и хочу, но когда я добавляю следующую запись, которая должна добавитьcя без проблем, у меня будет отлавливаться все то же исключение, что я добавляю null значение в not null column, и так до конца, пока я не создам новый контекст.

Comment: что то типа этого dbContext.ChangeTracker.Clear();